# Booting into read-only file system

Tags: boot, mount, read-only

I updated Ubuntu Desktop(although I'm using it as a server) from 14.04 to 16.04 on ssh. After completion and rebooting, it boots into read-only file system.

```
root@Server:/# touch a
touch: cannot touch 'a': Read-only file system
```

I tried `mount -o remount,rw /`, but the output is `mount: can't find UUID=/dev/sda1`. I think UUID is somehow changed to /dev/sda1. This is the contents of /etc/fstab.

```
root@Server:/# cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=/dev/sda1 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# UUID=643d9cab-177e-4eee-a52f-224ebf0bc405 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=481bc70a-eb80-4040-93a1-696c46faa638 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

I think I should comment the line UUID=/dev/sda1 and uncomment the line UUID=643d9cab-... right below, but because the root file system was mounted as read-only, I couldn't. I don't know if this would help, but here's a part of kernel message.

```
root@KrootServer:/# dmesg|grep mount
[    1.794106] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    5.675605] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[   19.677056] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
```

So how do I fix this problem? I'm trying to fix the problem on ssh, so let me know if I need to physically access the machine.

[+] result of `sudo blkid`

```
ian0371@Server:~$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="643d9cab-177e-4eee-a52f-224ebf0bc405" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="0000e118-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="481bc70a-eb80-4040-93a1-696c46faa638" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="0000e118-05"`
```

Comment: Post the result of `sudo blkid`, as I find it odd that you have two entries for `/`, this show the `UUID` of all your devices

Comment: @George I appended the result of `sudo blkid`. I think /dev/sda1 is commented while upgrading ubuntu.

Comment: So now we know that which is which, boot into recovery mode and mount your file system like this `mount -o remount,rw /` then __comment out__ the `UUID=/dev/sda1 /     ext4    errors=remount-ro 0     1` part  and __umcomment__ the one under, then reboot normally and lets see if it corrects. __Note__ no spaces between `remount,rw`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now lets try this fix:

1. Boot into *recovery mode*
2. Select *root* from recovery menu.
3. Mount file system with:

   ```
   mount -o remount,rw /
   ```
4. Using vim or nano change your `/etc/fstab` like so:

   ```
   #UUID=/dev/sda1 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
   UUID=643d9cab-177e-4eee-a52f-224ebf0bc405 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
   ```
5. Then exit and select *resume* from recovery menu, that should fix your issue.

Comment: I finally could access the server and manage to boot into recovery mode. Even in recovery mode "mount" command failed for the same reason. I finally managed to fix the problem by fixing grub script, where it said "ro" and changed it to "rw".

Comment: If there is an error in `etc/fstab` (e.g. wrong UUID) the command `mount -o remount,rw /` fails.

Comment: @IanSong I was STUCK for HOURS and you helped me with the solution. However, it's worth mentioning that you have to replace the whole **`errors=remount-ro`** with **`rw`** to have access, not just changing the last `o` to `w` as you suggested. See [here](http://www.didattica.agentgroup.unimo.it/didattica/curriculum/renzo/fstab/fstab.html) the list of options to the 4th column

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem when booting into a copied root filesystem (I forgot to adjust UUID values in /etc/fstab). It turns out `mount -o remount` still looks in /etc/fstab if you don't specify a device. It worked when manually specifying a device:

```
mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda1 /
```

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong in your /etc/fstab.

```
UUID=/dev/sda1 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# UUID=643d9cab-177e-4eee-a52f-224ebf0bc405 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0
```

THe first line is wrong, /dev/sda1 isn't a uuid. The second line looks like the correct one. Put a # in front of the first line, and remove it on the line below.

You can verify the UUID by `blkid /dev/sda1` .. if it differs, change the one in /etc/fstab so that it matches.

OR you can remove the UUID= in front of /dev/sda1

Comment: Wow!  Someone downvoted this???  +1 from me!

Comment: As stated, the whole file system is mounted as read-only and I CANNOT change /etc/fstab or any file.