# Keyboard and mouse not responding at reboot after xorg.conf update

Tags: keyboard, xorg, mouse, touchpad

I have a MacBook Pro with trackpad that was very sensitive with my Ubuntu Cinnamon 16.04. 
I tried some customization found here and there on the net, and finaly edit the xorg.conf file.
But after reboot, my keyboard and my mouse are not responding. The time on my screen is updated every minute, so i think the system is not freezed.

My idea was to launch a terminal to reset the xorg.conf file.
I tried 
CTRL+ALT+T
CTRL+ALT+Fn 1...7
but this is not working, so i guess my keyboard is not working.

I tried a usb mouse, and the cursor is not moving...

I am using Refind, and I was not able to start a way to start ubuntu in mimimal model, where i would be able to launch some command lines.

Edit : I was able to enter to Grub boot menu after holding the ESC. button. I can enter In Advanced Option for Ubuntu. But if i select this, nothing happens, my screen stays grey.
Edit 2: After getting to the avdanced menu, if i hit esc, i go back to the menu one. Selecting advanced option again, I can access the recovery mode.
In recovery mode, i selected root
There I was not able to execute

```
#sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg

xserver-xorg is not installed
```

Nor

```
#sudo X -configure

Could not create lock file in /tmp/.tx0-lock
```

I tried

```
#sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

but it is telling me that the system is read only

EDIT 3:

```
#cat /etc/fstab
    # : was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=fff03159-4eda-49b6-b93d-6be3eb655560e /       ext4     errors=ermount-ro 
0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=67E3-17ED /boot/efi     vfat   umask=0077    0   1
```

[result of cat /etc/fstab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ucy0.jpg)

Comment: I'm sorry, It's unclear at lest to me what you mean by `Ubuntu Cinemanon`

Comment: @ElderGeek, I suspect the reference is to the Cinnamon Desktop (Gnome 3-based).

Comment: You aren't going to be able to fix anything until you manage to remount the system read/write You will likely find [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/876510/booting-into-read-only-file-system) useful or [this.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47538/how-to-make-read-only-file-system-writable) [edit] the content of `/etc/fstab` into your post if you need further assistance.

Comment: @richbl Perhaps we will know for certain soon.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo. I am using Cinnamon Desktop.

Comment: @elder geek : I am using a dual boot. Is there a risk when doing the changes in fstab ? I have no data to loose on my ubuntu boot, so i prefer to keep my mac data safe and reinstalling a new distrib from scratch than taking risk of altering my data on my mac os boot

Comment: @NoobOverflow [edit]ing the content of your Ubuntu /etc/fstab into your post is not the same as altering the file. Please read my comment again. I am NOT suggesting any changes to your system at this time. I'm simply attempting to assist you in providing sufficient information to clarify what your problem actually is.  Am I correct in assuming that because you are asking here you are asking about the Ubuntu 16.04 boot?

Comment: Yes you are correct. I am asking about the Ubuntu boot. Keyboard and trackpad are working fine on my My MacOS boot. I add a caption of the result of /cat/fstab. Sorry for the misunderstanding: english is not my first langage and i understood edit as changing the file.